# Data Modeling - how to handle two, dependent "status" columns?

Tags: sql, mysql, data-modeling

I've run across something that's bugging me just enough that I wanted to come here and seek out a sort of "best practice" type of advice from you guys (et gals)

I have a table in my model, let's call it `prospect`.  Two separate external systems can provide an update for rows in this table, but only as a "status" of that record in those respective systems.

I need to store those statuses locally.  Initial idea, of course, it just to make two nullable foreign keys.  Something like this.

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| prospect_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ext_status_1_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ext_status_2_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In this example there would be, of course, two tables that hold id/value pairs for statuses.

Here's the catch - `ext_status_2_id` will *always* be NULL unless `ext_status_1_id` is `1` (this is just how the business rules work).

Have I modeled this correctly?  I just have this nagging voice in the back of my brain telling me that "not every row in prospect will need an `ext_status_2_id` so this might not be right".

If it matters, this is MySQL 5.0.45 and I'm using InnoDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is an in-built dependency for Status2 on Status1, why not just have a single status field on the prospect table, and create Status2 as a property on the Status1 table?  It is certainly normalized heavily in this fashion but having the data structure this way speaks about the dependency of Status2 on Status1.

Comment: What idiot would vote this down?  I'm really curious.  You have no idea what you're talking about if you voted this down.

Comment: Thank Roland.  I apologize to whoever voted me down, but sometimes I get emotional :) A better way to phrase it would have been: Can whomever voted me down please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably fine. But since you'll always only use 1 of the 2, you could model it as :

ext_status_type (either 1 or 2) and ext_status for the actual id.

I would probably do the same as you did, because it might be easier to build indexes around this and both numbers appear to have a true different meaning.

If there will be more statuses (3,4,5,6) I would consider the first approach in my answer.

Comment: to clarify, I won't necessarily use "1 of the 2", but more that "the 2nd augments a specific value of the first"

Answer (score 0):

What are the possible `ext__status__1`? Will `ext__status__2` have a value only if `status__1=1`? What is `status__1=2`? I agree partially with Nissan Fan. Is there, however a direct dependency between `status__1` and `Status__2`? Is there a Functional dependency of the form `status__1 -> Status__2`? 
 If there is no such dependence then keeping `status__1` and `Status__2` in a separate table does not solve your problem.